# Copy a value, but don't get affected when it changes

Tags: c#, xna

I'm programming an AI for a submarine, where it 'sees' a convoy when it is above water, but predicts the convoy's position while it's underwater. When I copy the position of the convoy to a Vector2 within the submarine class, this Vector2 is still changed whenever the convoy's position is updated. So how can I copy the position of the convoy without having that position tied to the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Vector2 vec2 = new Vector2(vec1.X,vec1.Y);
```

instead of

```
Vector2 vec2 = vec1;
```

yet?
**Edit:**
You can run through the array/list and add a new vector to a new list.

```
for(int i=0;i<originalList.Count;i++){
    newList.Add(new Vector2(originalList[i].X,originalList[i].Y));
}
```

**Edit2:**
When you "copy" a non-primitive variable, such as your custom class, then you actually make a new "reference" and not a "copy". In order to make a copy, you have to make a new instance, and copy the primitives from the original instance to the new one.
[Primitives.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks! How would I be able to do something like that with a class - I have a ConvoyShip class, and an array to contain them all, and it would be much easier if I could copy the array to one inside the sub's class and do all the prediction, but then I run into the same problem again! (I'm a bit of a newbie, so sorry if this is a dumb question)

Comment: How can I do something like that for something that isn't a Vector2 though?

Comment: You got to copy the primitives.